# Hide files in developer tools?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hidden-files

So, I want to apologize ahead of time but I've been googling and stack overflowing for an answer to this question and I just can't find a satisfactory one.

I know that Facebook uses React and, although I don't know what software architecture they use (MVC, Client-Server etc.), I can't see any react files or react components in the dev tools sources tab on any browser.

I'll show you an example in my own react app using create-react-app that shows all my files:

Create-react-apps dev tools sources:

[image: create-react-apps dev tools sources]

However, when I go to Facebook's page, I don't see anything like that. I see this:

Facebook's dev tools sources:

[image: Facebook's dev tools sources]

This isn't only true of react apps, but just node apps I've made as well. Now, I want to know where all of this information is on facebook's page.... Where are the components? Why can't I see them? Where are all the post and get requests being run? How can I put breakpoints in the code for debugging? I mean, I don't even see an HTML page besides the elements tab! And, most importantly, how do I do the same thing to hide my files?

It seems like it adds an extra layer of security that I would think is preferable on all public websites. Once again, thanks in advance and, as far as I know, the answer to this is nowhere near obvious.

Comment: just remove your `.map` files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I admit, this one little bit confusing when you are quite new on the web development.

You **can see your files** (source code) via devtool because you also upload your `.map` files which help map your bundled/minified code into the the original readable one.

However, this is super helpful on development environment, but quite dangerous on production. What you need to do just remove the `.map` files, as comment suggested.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I now understand what I have to do, but the problem is, I don't see any `.map` files in my directories. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure? try search sub-directories also, i tried open your web, and my browser detect the map file `main.1795cc73.js.map`